# Qt QGraphicsProxyWidget hiding other QGraphicsProxyWidgets

Tags: qt, hide, qgraphicsview, qgraphicspixmapitem, qgraphicswidget

I'm working on a Slotmachine with QGraphicsScene and -View and I'm close to the end of that project. But now I want to add a small rect to the winning-lines that shows the amount of won credits in that line. The rect is a QLabel in a QGraphicsProxyWidget. I don't know if thats the best way to solve this problem but I'm not able to find a better solution at the moment. I'm setting the proxyWidget to not visible in the constructor of the label but when I'm setting this proxyWidget to visible other proxyWidgets in the scene disappear. And I just dont understand why. It's not hiding every proxyWidgets.

[image: The Problem.]

As you can see on the picture there's a red rect in the middle of the first square of the winning line. This is causing the problem. It is hiding the lower white border which is a QGraphicsPixmapItem and the first of the normally three QGraphicsProxyWidgets at the bottom, stake(this is not visible), last gain(letzter Gewinn), credit(Guthaben). I don't know why its not hiding the other Widgets on the bottom because they are all equal. As you can see its not hiding the complete lower border. I just don't know why this happens and why it just happens to the lower border and the left widget on the bottom and not to any other elements. I just don't know how to fix a problem like that.

It's a bit long to read but I don't know how to really describe the problem or how I could show you in the Code. I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using an QGraphicsTextItem. totally forgot that it is existing. Thanks to the QT Forum.